# Plotting Multiple graphs on Secondary Y axis of AChartEngine

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am using AChartEngine to plot Multiple Y axis Graph plot, The thing is I plotted five Graph lines on primary Y axis ,but when plotting five graph lines on secondary yaxis ,it shows only one and that is the last plotted one here is my code ,anyhelp will be thankfull

code concerning secondary Y axis

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
    values.clear();
    values.add(new double[]  { mWeightFirstList.get(0),
            mWeightFirstList.get(1), mWeightFirstList.get(2),
            mWeightFirstList.get(3), mWeightFirstList.get(4),
            mWeightFirstList.get(5), mWeightFirstList.get(6),
            mWeightFirstList.get(7), mWeightFirstList.get(8),
            mWeightFirstList.get(9), mWeightFirstList.get(10),
            mWeightFirstList.get(11), mWeightFirstList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "97%" }, x, values, 1);
    values.add(new double[]  { mWeightSecondList.get(0),
            mWeightSecondList.get(1), mWeightSecondList.get(2),
            mWeightSecondList.get(3), mWeightSecondList.get(4),
            mWeightSecondList.get(5), mWeightSecondList.get(6),
            mWeightSecondList.get(7), mWeightSecondList.get(8),
            mWeightSecondList.get(9), mWeightSecondList.get(10),
            mWeightSecondList.get(11), mWeightSecondList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "75%" }, x, values, 2);
    values.add(new double[]  { mWeightThirdList.get(0),
            mWeightThirdList.get(1), mWeightThirdList.get(2),
            mWeightThirdList.get(3), mWeightThirdList.get(4),
            mWeightThirdList.get(5), mWeightThirdList.get(6),
            mWeightThirdList.get(7), mWeightThirdList.get(8),
            mWeightThirdList.get(9), mWeightThirdList.get(10),
            mWeightThirdList.get(11), mWeightThirdList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "50%" }, x, values, 3);
    values.add(new double[]  { mWeightFourthList.get(0),
            mWeightFourthList.get(1), mWeightFourthList.get(2),
            mWeightFourthList.get(3), mWeightFourthList.get(4),
            mWeightFourthList.get(5), mWeightFourthList.get(6),
            mWeightFourthList.get(7), mWeightFourthList.get(8),
            mWeightFourthList.get(9), mWeightFourthList.get(10),
            mWeightFourthList.get(11), mWeightFourthList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "25%" }, x, values, 4);
    values.add(new double[]  { mWeightFifthList.get(0),
            mWeightFifthList.get(1), mWeightFifthList.get(2),
            mWeightFifthList.get(3), mWeightFifthList.get(4),
            mWeightFifthList.get(5), mWeightFifthList.get(6),
            mWeightFifthList.get(7), mWeightFifthList.get(8),
            mWeightFifthList.get(9), mWeightFifthList.get(10),
            mWeightFifthList.get(11), mWeightFifthList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "35%" }, x, values, 5);
    GraphicalView mView = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(context,
            dataset, renderer, 0.3f);
    return mView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using the following code

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
    values.clear();
    List<double[]> values1 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    List<double[]> values2 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    List<double[]> values3 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    List<double[]> values4 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    List<double[]> values5 = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    values1.add(new double[]  { mWeightFirstList.get(0),
            mWeightFirstList.get(1), mWeightFirstList.get(2),
            mWeightFirstList.get(3), mWeightFirstList.get(4),
            mWeightFirstList.get(5), mWeightFirstList.get(6),
            mWeightFirstList.get(7), mWeightFirstList.get(8),
            mWeightFirstList.get(9), mWeightFirstList.get(10),
            mWeightFirstList.get(11), mWeightFirstList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "97%" }, x, values1, 1);
    values2.add(new double[]  { mWeightSecondList.get(0),
            mWeightSecondList.get(1), mWeightSecondList.get(2),
            mWeightSecondList.get(3), mWeightSecondList.get(4),
            mWeightSecondList.get(5), mWeightSecondList.get(6),
            mWeightSecondList.get(7), mWeightSecondList.get(8),
            mWeightSecondList.get(9), mWeightSecondList.get(10),
            mWeightSecondList.get(11), mWeightSecondList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "75%" }, x, values2, 1);
    values3.add(new double[]  { mWeightThirdList.get(0),
            mWeightThirdList.get(1), mWeightThirdList.get(2),
            mWeightThirdList.get(3), mWeightThirdList.get(4),
            mWeightThirdList.get(5), mWeightThirdList.get(6),
            mWeightThirdList.get(7), mWeightThirdList.get(8),
            mWeightThirdList.get(9), mWeightThirdList.get(10),
            mWeightThirdList.get(11), mWeightThirdList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "50%" }, x, values3, 1);
    values4.add(new double[]  { mWeightFourthList.get(0),
            mWeightFourthList.get(1), mWeightFourthList.get(2),
            mWeightFourthList.get(3), mWeightFourthList.get(4),
            mWeightFourthList.get(5), mWeightFourthList.get(6),
            mWeightFourthList.get(7), mWeightFourthList.get(8),
            mWeightFourthList.get(9), mWeightFourthList.get(10),
            mWeightFourthList.get(11), mWeightFourthList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "25%" }, x, values4, 1);
    values5.add(new double[]  { mWeightFifthList.get(0),
            mWeightFifthList.get(1), mWeightFifthList.get(2),
            mWeightFifthList.get(3), mWeightFifthList.get(4),
            mWeightFifthList.get(5), mWeightFifthList.get(6),
            mWeightFifthList.get(7), mWeightFifthList.get(8),
            mWeightFifthList.get(9), mWeightFifthList.get(10),
            mWeightFifthList.get(11), mWeightFifthList.get(12) });
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "3% (Weight)" }, x, values5, 1);
    GraphicalView mView = ChartFactory.getCubeLineChartView(context,
            dataset, renderer, 0.3f);
    return mView;
```